# Django Redirect to previous page, if user is not allowed to access page

Tags: django, http, https

I have created a custom decorator to restrict access to a view based on an user's group. If a user is not allowed to access the view he/she gets redirected to my landing page '/' (in code below)... How can I redirect the user to the site he/she was coming from?

I am close but I don't know how to fix this.

Thank you so much

Please see:

```
def allowed_users(allowed_roles=[]):
    def decorator(view_func):
        def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):

            group = ''
            if request.user.groups.exists():
                group = request.user.groups.all()[0].name
            if group in allowed_roles:
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.HTTP('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
        return wrapper_func
    return decorator
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can work with:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
```

Your decorator however is a bit odd, since it works with the *first* group. But if a user belongs to *multiple* groups, it is thus possible that it will first take one group, and for another request another group.

It looks like you simply want to know if there is at least one group with as name an element in the `allowed_roles`, so:

```
def allowed_users(allowed_roles=[]):
    def decorator(view_func):
        def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if request.user.groups.filter(name__in=allowed_roles).exists():
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
        return wrapper_func
    return decorator
```

Furthermore typically redirecting is not really how a server responds to a request of a client when the client is not authorized, so a HTTP 401 response.